Setting an HTML5 form as invalid even when all elements are considered valid?
Often, a form's elements are valid based on the client-side validations, but the entire submission is invalid, based on the combined form's values and the state of the back-end.
I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can mark that form as invalid (i.e. such that checkValidity() returns false and the :invalid pseudo-selector is matched).
Stuff I have tried:

HTMLFormElement does not seem to support setCustomValidity().
Inserting a <input type=hidden name="wholeForm"> into the form, calling setCustomValidity("whole form is invalid"), then reportValidity().  This didn't work, despite raising no errors: the form and the field returned true for checkValidity(). I'm assuming that this is because the field is hidden.
A text field with display: none. I get an error that the control is not focusable (which makes sense).
A text field using an sr-only-type CSS class that basically makes the control invisible to a standard web browser, it does work, however this leaves the control in the accessibility tree, which I don't want, since it's just a hack to put an error on.

Does anyone have any ideas or techniques on how this could be done?
The reasoning for this is to try to unify all error reporting for a form, both client-side and server-side, to reduce the # of ways in which errors are reported, but also adhere as closely as possible to web/browser APIs.  I would use the form:invalid as a way to locate elements to provide the user an error message.
